# How do I install git on Ubuntu and manage my files?

Tags: ubuntu, git

I have Ubuntu on my PC.

I want to make all code inside `/var/www/` git-versioned.

Where is the best to put my git files and how do I setup git for files inside `/var/www/`?

Edit:

Better explanation for my question:

1. I need to setup git server on my computer that will be only accessible to all PC on local network and for the rest. (the location for my opinion of git server should be /srv/git/)
2. The files on my computer that i want them to be with git support under /var/www/

Thanks

Comment: repo inside web-root is extremely bad idea from the POV of security

Comment: why its bad security?

Comment: possibility to open data in repo in case of site-hacks or server-misconfiguration

Comment: the repo should be under /srv/git/ and the code download from git to /var/www/ this what i mean

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Installing the `git` client

Git comes in the Ubuntu packages.

```
sudo apt-get -y install git
```

After that, you can easily just create an empty Git repository wherever your code is.

```
cd /var/www/some-project
git init
git add some-file
git commit -m "First commit."
```

Although it can be argued that keeping version controlled files in `/var/www` is not a good idea. You should probably only deploy projects there.

---

#### Managing `git` repositories

If you want a Git server and push your stuff somewhere, you should look at [Gitosis](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Gitosis). On Ubuntu, that is:

```
sudo apt-get -y install gitosis
```

The Ubuntu community manual also has an [extensive tutorial on setting up Gitosis](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Git), as well as the Arch wiki I linked to above. The default setup will take care of where to put your files, in this case `/srv/gitosis`.

If you want more control, grab Gitosis [from GitHub](https://github.com/res0nat0r/gitosis) instead and change the `--home` option for the home directory.

```
sudo adduser \
    --system \
    --shell /bin/sh \
    --gecos 'git version control' \
    --group \
    --disabled-password \
    --home /srv/git \
    git
```

Then follow the steps in the manual (beware, the Ubuntu version has the user `gitosis`, whereas the one from GitHub uses `git`).

You'll find [yet another tutorial](http://blog.agdunn.net/?p=277) here, so this stuff is fairly well documented.

Comment: NITPICK: On all recent releases `git-core` is a transitional package, that depends on `git`.  The package has no files.

Comment: see my edit please

Comment: @Yosef Updated answer, but as Zoredache said, this depends on your configuration needs and it's almost impossible to give an answer. You will have to work on this yourself too.

Answer (score 4):

An extremely short startup would be to do something like this.

```
sudo apt-get install git
cd /var/www
git init
git add .
git commit
```

You would then have a repository of all the files under `/var/www`.

You probably should take the time to read the docs though.

- http://git-scm.com/documentation
- http://book.git-scm.com/
- http://progit.org/book/
- [Getting started with GIT {search}](https://www.google.com/webhp?q=getting%20started%20with%20git)

Comment: thanks!but where will be located git version files?

Comment: Git is a distributed version control system.  It will keep the files in `~/.git/` unless you clone, setup remotes or perform some other action to push or pull your changes to a different location.

Comment: P.S. If you can afford a few dollers for a set of videos, I recommend http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920017462.do.  There chapter on cloning is available as a free-demo, so you might want to watch that.

Comment: see my edit please

Comment: Please **see the documentation** that @slhck, and I linked to.  If you intend to run a server there are a large number of options that you should consider.  IMO opinion it is unreasonable to expect us to give you an answer that describes how to setup, and manage a server given the extreme lack of detail you have provided.